# Click one class but element show in another class

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * jewels.length)
    html += '<div class="Card1 ' + jewels[rand] + '" id="ship' + i + '" style="top:72px; left:245px;" ></div>'
    jewels.splice(rand, 1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    html += '<div class="Card2" id="stac' + i + '" style="top:' + (135 + (i * 13)) + 'px; left:245px;" ></div>'
}

$('.Card1').click(function () {

});
```

when I click in card1 class I want to show random 4 items(out of 20) in class card2?

Comment: can u create link pls

Comment: your question is not clear enough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's not at all clear to me what you're asking here, or what the context is of the block of Javascript you've included.  Where do you want those `.card2` items to be shown, and what does "shown" mean in this context?  (E.g. were they previously `display: none`, or positioned offscreen, or hiding on a deselected tab, or not present in the DOM at all?)

Comment: It may be a good idea to come up with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is an excellent place to post small snippets of HTML and Javascript to demonstrate the issue you're facing.

Comment: In for loop 1 I take 20 items randomly.In for loop 2 I take four class.now I want to show random four item in card2 class when I click card1 class.

Comment: @7asif7 I'm afraid I still don't understand what you mean without an example.  It's clear to you what "for loop 1" means, and what it's supposed to be doing, but it doesn't really give anyone else an idea of what's happening.